# Prove an inequality $\frac{x^2}{1+y}+\frac{y^2}{1+x}\ge 1$ where $x,y \ge 0$ and $x+y=2$.

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, jensen-inequality, tangent-line-method

I was trying to solve the following:
$$ \frac{x^2}{1+y}+\frac{y^2}{1+x}\ge 1$$
$$x^2(1+x)+y^2(1+y)\ge (1+y)(1+x)$$
$$x^3+x^2+y^3+y^2 \ge 1+y+x+xy$$
$$(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)+x^2+y^2 \ge 1+y+x+xy$$
substitute $x+y=2$
$$2(x^2-xy+y^2)+x^2+y^2 \ge 3+xy$$
$$2((x+y)^2-3xy)+(x+y)^2-2xy \ge 3+xy$$
$$2(4-3xy)+4-2xy \ge 3+xy$$
$$12-8xy \ge 3+xy$$
$$1 \ge xy$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And now you can use AM-GM: $$1=\frac{(x+y)^2}{4}\geq\frac{(2\sqrt{xy})^2}{4}= xy.$$

I think the following way a bit of better.

By C-S we obtain:
$$\frac{x^2}{1+y}+\frac{y^2}{1+x}\geq\frac{(x+y)^2}{2+x+y}=1.$$
We can use also the Tangent Line method.

Indeed,
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^2}{1+y}-1=\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{x^2}{3-x}-\frac{1}{2}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\frac{2x^2+x-3}{3-x}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\frac{(x-1)(2x+3)}{3-x}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{(x-1)(2x+3)}{3-x}-\frac{5}{2}(x-1)\right)
=\frac{9}{4}\sum_{cyc}\frac{(x-1)^2}{3-x}\geq0.$$

Comment: oh. thanks about AM-GM. But what is C-S?

Comment: It's Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: For all positives $b_i$ we have $\frac{a_1^2}{b_1}+\frac{a_2^2}{b_2}+...+\frac{a_n^2}{b_n}\geq\frac{(a_1+a_2+...+a_n)^2}{b_1+b_2+..+b_n}.$

Answer (score 4):

We have 
$$ \frac{x^2}{1+y}+\frac{y^2}{1+x}= \frac{x^2}{3-x}+\frac{y^2}{3-y}.$$
Put $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{3-x}.$ Since 
$$
f''(x)=\frac{18}{3-x} >0,
$$
$f(x)$ is convex function for $x<3.$ 
 Then by Jensen inequality
$$
\frac{x^2}{3-x}+\frac{y^2}{3-y}=f(x)+f(y) \geq 2 f(\frac{x+y}{2})=2 f(1)=2 \cdot \frac{1}{2}=1.
$$

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: Leox +1 for your answer...

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact, $$x=1+a$$ and $$y=1-a$$
where$0<a<1$.
It will work, after you have substituted in the place of $x$ and $y$.respectively.
Update 1:
After substituting , we get,
$$\dfrac{4+8a^2}{4-a^2}\geq 1 \Rightarrow \dfrac{9a^2}{4-a^2}\geq0$$
which is certainly true.
And remember we can always consider $x=1+a$ and $y=1-a$ beacuse $x,y\in$R.

Answer (score 0):

Using Titu's lemma we get 
$$ \frac{x^2}{1+y}+\frac{y^2}{1+x}\ge \frac {{(x+y)}^2}{2+x+y}$$

Using the condition $x+y=2$ we get 
$$ \frac{x^2}{1+y}+\frac{y^2}{1+x}\ge \frac {2^2}{2+2}=1$$

Q. E. D